Share geometry between objects, or way to "track to" within the same object
Good day to everyone. I am struggling doing one of the following two things that are needed in my project.
I found modes of "tracking to" between two objects (using vectors substraction), while I would need to "track to" two geometries generated within the same object. One of them is a geometry picked through a switch, the other is a point which is the target to which the instanced geometry should point to.
I am not sure whether methods like this can be used within the same object without having an external target.

Another option could be to be able to export the choice of the switch node as either the geometry itself or a named attribute identifying the chosen geometry, so that I can pick it up in another object and realize the "track to" method between to separate objects.

Is any of the two options possible? In case you need the blend file with all the data, I can upload it somewhere after having replaced the geometries I have to create, as they are reserved.

I'm not clear what you want. Are you perhaps asking how to make one object rotate to point at another? You don't need two separate geometry groups within a single mesh, right?

Thanks for your interest. Geometry of already separated into different groups into the mesh, and yes if possible I would like to keep everything inside the same mesh. Not at the computer right now but I can post an image of the entire setup later on.

Nevermind, I sorted it out. I just picked up the wrong value for the target (its initial position vs its current position, so the geometry wasn't moving. It's ok now, and everything is inside the same mesh.

It is definitely possible to realize the "track to" within the same mesh. My problem in the setup not functioning was that I plugged the target's initial position (the one from which it started rotating) instead of the position corrected after applying the desired rotation.

